# Entity Framework Generic Insert Method Assign Guid to Primary Key

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, generics

Is there a way to generically identity the primary key (always a single column) and assign a Guid in a generic Insert method:

For example I have who dbSet classes.  Both have a single-field primary key of type Guid:

```
public class Person
{
   [Key]
   [Required]
   public Guid personId {get; set;}
   public string name {get; set;}
}

public class City
{
    public Guid cityId {get; set;}
    public string name (get; set;
}
```

I want to me able to do something like this:

```
City city = new City {
   name = "Seattle";
};
Update<City>(city);
```

Using a generic method like this:

```
public T Insert<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
   // Instead of using code like this for each entity type
   if (entity is City)
   {
       City cEntity = entity as City
       cEntity.cityId = Guid.NewGuid();
   }

   // I want to be able to do something generically like this
   entity.PrimaryKey = Guid.NewGuid();

   // Add
   this._db.Set<T>().Add(item);
}
```

Is this crazy or should I just be having the database automatically add a Guid into the table upon Insert?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to find out the member that either of Guid type or have KeyAttribute

```
var byType = entity.GetType().GetProperties().First(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(Guid));
//or
var byAtttribute = entity.GetType().GetProperties().First(x=>x.CustomAttributes.Any(a=>a.AttributeType.Name=="KeyAttribute"));
```

then set the value

```
byType.SetValue(entity, Guid.NewGuid());
//or
byAttribute.SetValue(entity, Guid.NewGuid());
```

but this is guaranteed to be slower, and unless you need to assign a predefined Guid for some reason, it's better to let the database handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface for the id:

```cs
public interface IHasGuid
{
    Guid ID { get; set; }
}
```

Then let your classes implement that interface:

```cs
public class Person : IHasGuid
{
   [Key]
   [Required]
   public Guid ID {get; set;}
   public string name {get; set;}
}

public class City : IHasGuid
{
    public Guid ID {get; set;}
    public string name (get; set;
}
```

Then you can access the `ID` property wherever `T` is `IHasGuid` :

```cs
public T Insert<T>(T entity) where T : class, IHasGuid
{
   entity.ID = Guid.NewGuid();

   // ...
}
```